# How can I draw two triangles using index buffer?

Tags: c++, opengl, index-buffer

I wish to draw two triangles (having one common vertex) with two different colors using an index buffer. How can I do so?

Without using an index buffer, two such triangles can easily be drawn by just repeating the common vertex data. Yes, I can still use an index buffer. But in that case, there is no advantage of using an index buffer. My vertex data is given below:

```
glm::vec4 positions[] = {
    glm::vec4(+0.0f, +0.0f, +0.0f, +1.0f),
    glm::vec4(+1.0f, +1.0f, +0.0f, +1.0f),
    glm::vec4(-1.0f, +1.0f, +0.0f, +1.0f),
    glm::vec4(-1.0f, -1.0f, +0.0f, +1.0f),
    glm::vec4(+1.0f, -1.0f, +0.0f, +1.0f)
    };
glm::vec4 colors[] = {
    glm::vec4(+1.0f, +0.0f, +0.0f, +1.0f),
    glm::vec4(+1.0f, +0.0f, +0.0f, +1.0f),
    glm::vec4(+1.0f, +0.0f, +0.0f, +1.0f),
    glm::vec4(+0.0f, +1.0f, +0.0f, +1.0f),
    glm::vec4(+0.0f, +1.0f, +0.0f, +1.0f)
    };

int indices[] = {
    0, 1, 2,
    0, 3, 4
    };
```

I set the attribute layout in the following way:

```
int positionStride = sizeof(vertex->position) + sizeof(vertex->color);
   int positionOffset = 0;
   glEnableVertexAttribArray(vertex->POSITION);
   glVertexAttribPointer(vertex->POSITION, vertex->position.length(), 
       GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, positionStride, (const void*)positionOffset);

int colorStride = sizeof(vertex->color) + sizeof(vertex->position);
   int colorOffset = positionOffset + sizeof(vertex->position);
   glEnableVertexAttribArray(vertex->COLOR);
   glVertexAttribPointer(vertex->COLOR, vertex->color.length(), GL_FLOAT, 
      GL_FALSE, colorStride, (const void*)colorOffset);
```

My vertex class is defined as follows:

```
class Vertex
{
public:
    Vertex();
    ~Vertex();
    enum Attribute
    {
        POSITION,
        COLOR
    };
}
```

Using the above set up I get a perfect red triangle but not the green one as expected. Moreover, despite having only two unique colors, I have to repeat the colors. Since the triangle is the simplest type of geometric object which forms a plane, there are many cases where two adjacent triangles (sharing one or two vertices) need to be rendered with different constant colors. I want to take advantage of using an index buffer and at the same time also want to render two adjacent triangles with constant colors.

Using two unique colors instead of 5 redundant colors will be an added bonus.

Is there any efficient way to accomplish this?

[@ Nicol Bolas: I checked that link even before posting this question. Since I am allowed to use only one index buffer, the trick is really in ordering the indices to fit both the position and color data. However, there are 5 positions and two unique colors. If I arrange the indices to fit the position, I have to define

```
int indices[] = {
    0, 1, 2,
    0, 3, 4
    };
```

However, if I wish to fit the color data, I need the indices as

```
int indices[] = {
    0, 1, 2,
    3, 3, 4
    };
```

provided I duplicate the colors.
]

Comment: Without more code I can't see why you get only the red triangle and not the green on too. Some projection setting? Indexed drawing is useful when there are many repeated vertices. The advantage takes place when you need to transfer to the GPU much less data.

Comment: @Ripi2 More code added.